# LINQPad access built-in DataContext in extension methods

Tags: extension-methods, linqpad

Can I access the **this** object in my extension methods?

So far this is what I have:

```
void Main() {

    IQueryable<DataContextTable> list = DataContextTables.First().NewMethod(this);

}

public static class ExtensionMethods {

    public static IQueryable<DataContextTable> NewMethod(this DataContextTable table, TypedDataContext context) {
        return context.DataContextTables.Where(item => item.SomeProperty == true).AsQqueryable();
    }

}
```

as you can see I still need to pass the TypedDataContext as parameters to my extension methods.  Is there any other way I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a **static member** of type **TypedDataSet** and "initialize" it in the **Main()** function with **this**.

```
void Main() {

    ExtensionMethods.Context = this;
    IQueryable<DataContextTable> list = DataContextTables.First().NewMethod(this);

}

public static class ExtensionMethods {

    public static TypedDataSet Context;

    public static IQueryable<DataContextTable> NewMethod(this DataContextTable table) {
        return Context.DataContextTables.Where(item => item.SomeProperty == true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to acermate433s' answer, but In LINQPad 4 I created a static member of type **TypedDataContext**:

```
void Main()
{
    MyExtensions.Context = this;
}

public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static TypedDataContext Context { get; set; }
    // your method here
}
```